# RDLC report A4 page size but extra page printed

Tags: report, whitespace, rdlc

I have a C# WinForms application that has an RDLC report. When I set the age size of the RDLC report to A4 size, the report at run time shows one extra white page. I need to reduce the width of the page to less than A4 size to get rid of the problem.

Along with that, the contents of the report look shifted to the left of the report.

Image at design time:

[image]

One extra letter after the c letter in the text will lead to a new white page at run time, though in the design it actually fits the whole page.

At run time, the report will appear like this image:

[image]

Text is aligned to the left leaving white space at the right. An interesting thing is that if I export the report to PDF format it looks as fine as it did at design time.

What might be wrong in my settings? This problem wasn't there until I did some updates in nuGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstalled report viewer and report designer and reinstall them again. Problem solved